# redrawing dc.js chart with right y axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I'm using dc.js and crossfilter.js to create a bunch of charts, and I've been able to successfully make it responsive, **EXCEPT** when I have a composite chart with a **Right Y Axis**.

[image: chart on first load]

[image: chart on window resize]

this is the resize function I'm using. How do I make this resize also reset where the Right Y Axis should start?

```
function resize(chartArr) {
    for(var i=0;i<chartArr.length;i++) {
        chartArr[i].root().select('svg')
            .attr('height', chartArr[i].height())
            .attr('width', chartArr[i].width());
        chartArr[i].rescale();
        chartArr[i].redraw();    
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your example and don't understand your resize code.  Can you create a jsFiddle or plunker?  Also have you seen this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BHzFr/44/)?

Comment: I made a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/sarahbkim/0aws9b8s/16/ -- although I don't know why it doesn't resize on the JSFiddle but works locally...  hopefully this kind of helps ?